# Unable to click on button which is situate on popup made by <div> using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, qooxdoo

HTML CODE

```
</div>
<div class="qx-outSet" qxselectable="off" style="overflow:...>
<div class="qx-button" tabindex="4" qxselectable="off" style="overflow:...>

******************************************** I have to click on bellow OK button ****************************
<div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; box-sizing: border-box; position: absolute; cursor: default; -moz-user-select: none; color: rgb(26, 26, 26); font-family: Arial,"Liberation Sans",sans-serif; font-size: 14px; left: 24px; top: 3px; width: 21px; height: 16px;" qxselectable="off" qxanonymous="true">OK</div>
</div>**
```

---

```
<div class="qx-button" tabindex="5" qxselectable="off" style="overflow: hidden; box-sizing: border-box; position: absolute; outline: medium none; -moz-user-select: none; cursor: default; padding: 3px 9px; left: 88px; top: 9px; width: 70px; height: 24px;">
<div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; box-sizing: border-box; position: absolute; cursor: default; -moz-user-select: none; color: rgb(26, 26, 26); font-family: Arial,"Liberation Sans",sans-serif; font-size: 14px; left: 12px; top: 3px; width: 45px; height: 16px;" qxselectable="off" qxanonymous="true">Cancel</div>
</div>
```

Right now I am working to automate web application which is developed in Qooxdoo frame work (it's javaScript framework) using selenium Web Driver with TestNG.
In this I already achieve a few things but there are some pop ups which are made using nested `<div>` and selenium popup handler can not handle that.
By using action class I can write in text area {by below mention selenium code }which is show in pop up (find the attachment) but I cannot click on the button ( OK , CANCEL).

```
// wd is WebDriver Object 
WebElement element = wd.findElement(By.className("qx-window")); // qx-window is class name of div in which text area is  present
Actions actions = new Actions(wd);
actions.moveToElement(element).click().perform();
Thread.sleep(5000);
// write text in text area 
wd.findElement(By.tagName("textarea")).sendKeys("TEST");

wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='demindoRoot']/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]")).click();  //  CODE TO CLICK ON "OK" BUTTON
```

I tried to switch focus by using action class again to the div in which the buttons are present but then also I cannot.

Error Log :

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"....

Comment: Provide `HTML` for target button and exception log f any raised. Also tell whether you've tried to use simple `click()` method to click the button

Comment: Hello Andersson, I attached whole HTML code in issue description ..... I have already tried the simple click() method , but i get an 2-3 errors i.e. element not found or element not clickable .....

Comment: There is a lot of information in your question but it can hardly help to solve your problem. Edit your question with short issue description, `HTML` of target button (+parent element), `Java` code you've tried to click button, exception log. This will make it clear and prevent downvotes

Comment: Updated the description .....

Comment: You should not use absolute `XPathes` like `".//*[@id='demindoRoot']/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]"`, but relative instead as they're more reliable and flexible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code and let me know in case of any exceptions:

```
wd.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='OK']")).click();
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Andersson .... For your valuable inputs on this . It works or me .... Can we use (By.xpath("//div[tabindex()='OK']")).click(); like (By.xpath("//div[text()='OK']")).click();   ?....

Comment: If you want to use attribute in `XPath`, use it as `//div[@tabindex="5"]`